# How to visualize help() output in graphical HTML?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, rendering, doxygen

Is there a command option or script to convert the Python's `help(className)` to an easier graphical form, preferably displayed in a web browser?

Can Doxygen do this? If so, how?

An example output of `help(MyClass)`:

```
Help on class MyClass in module my_class:

class MyClass(builtins.object)
 |  MyClass(p1=None, p2=0, **kwargs)
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, p1=None, p2=0, **kwargs)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  bit_clr(self, address, bit, *bits)
 |      Clear the specified bit (value of 0)
 |      
 |      :param address: The address to write to
 |      :param bit: The bit to set to a value of 0.
 |      :return: None
 |  
 |  bit_set(self, address, bit, *bits)
 |      Set the specified bit high (value of 1).
 |      
 |      :param address: The address to write to
 |      :param bit: The bit to set to a value of 1.
 |      :param bits: Additional bit to set to a value of 1.
 |      :return: None
 |  
 |  close(self)
 |  
 |  get_status(self)
 |      Get the last reported status.
 |      
 |      :return: Value of the last seen STATUS as an int
```

Comment: `pydoc -w module_name` from the command line or `import pydoc ; pydoc.writedoc(module_name)`